# Error loading image png file to react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

getting a `Error: Cannot find module 'schema-utils'` 
when trying to import image, seems a bit strange, I tried to import from the public directory aswell as directly within the Header component folder and get the same error. Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Header.css";
import title from "./insta-title.png";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="head">
      <header>
        <img src={title}></img>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you run ```npm install```

Comment: yes, no luck tho

Answer (score 0):

img tag in react written like this  so edit your code to be like this :

```
import React from "react"; 
import "../styles/Header.css"; 
import title from "./insta-title.png"; 
export default function Header() { return ( <div className="head"> <header> <img src={title}/></header> </div> );
```

Comment: What is different other than you took out all the nice spacing?

Comment: Read the full code  and img tag in react be written like this <img src={title}/>

Comment: So what you are saying is you should remove `</img>` from the image tag and use the self closing tag? (I am not the OP, trying to understand what you did since answer lacks an explanation)

Comment: Yes , this is how you can write img , input,hr tags in react

Comment: Self closing tag doesn't make a difference really but agree it should be self closed as there is nothing in-between `<img> ... </img>` but doesn't solve the issue