# cannot import image in react - schema-utils error

Tags: reactjs, image

I can't open an image in react with normal method:

```
import bgimg from './Elements/images/main.png'
```

Error is the following:

```
./src/Pages/Elements/images/main.png
Error: Cannot find module 'schema-utils'
```

Tried to delete node_modules and reinstall everything with `npm install` but didn't help. Any idea?
The image is definitely there, I can ctrl+click on it in VSCode.

It seems someone else had the same problem but it was not resolved:
[Error loading image png file to react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233436/error-loading-image-png-file-to-react-app)

Update:

I have 'resolved' the issue by restarting the whole process with `npx create-react-app`. It's not a real resolution, so all I can deduce from it: some error - which can't be resolved with npm install - happened during the project setup.
I kept the code, folder structure, files - everything - the same.

Comment: are you certain the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's in the right folder. Although I have copied the src folder into my other react app and it works there. There must be some npm error during the installation in my project. I close it and my resolution: pure luck.